# Access linked server from linked server directly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, paradox

I have two SQL Server instances:

- SQLSERVER64
- SQLSERVER32

In `SQLSERVER32`, I have a linked server to a Paradox database called `ParadoxDBLinkedServer`.

To access some of the Paradox tables in the server I just execute the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ParadoxDBLinkedServer]...Clients
```

Then, I need to access to these objects from the `SQLSERVER64` instance. In order to do so, I created a linked server called [`.\SQLSERVER32`] in this instance pointing to `SQLSERVER32`.

What I'm trying to do now is to access directly the `ParadoxDBLinkedServer` objects from the `SQLSERVER64` instance. I mean, accessing a linked server from another linked server.

The query I´m trying to run is the following one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [.\SQLSERVER32].[ParadoxDBLinkedServer ]...Clients
```

But I get this error:

> The number name '.\SQLSERVER32.ParadoxDBLinkedServer ...Clients' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.

Is there any way to perform an access like this? What am I missing here?

I'm trying to avoid creating a View for each table of the `ParadoxDBLinkedServer` in the `SQLSERVER32` instance to reduce overhead.

Comment: You get this error when you have excess objects in your four part naming convention: `[.\SQLSERVER32].[ParadoxDBLinkedServer ].[Schema_Name].[Table_Name]` try this..

Comment: @Darshan_Viswanath_BI, the schema is missing. Actually it is in the default schema. But trying [.\SQLSERVER32 ].[ParadoxDBLinkedServer].[default].Clients I get: The OLE DB provider "%ls" for linked server "%ls" does not contain the table "%ls". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: Can you log into both servers and do a `select * from [Database].[dbo].[Client]` ? Prefixing with [ParadoxDBLinkedServer ] should be your solution. If the table does not exist or you do not necessary permissions you will know it.

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but hopefully can be helpful to someone else who comes to this post later. If you can use `openquery` then something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([.\SQLSERVER32], 'SELECT * FROM   OPENQUERY([ParadoxDBLinkedServer ],''SELECT * FROM Clients'')' )
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from openquery (Linkedservername,'select * from tablename')